# Как экранировать все спецсимволы в строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В терминале перед каждым спецсимволом (пробелом и п.) ставится `\`.
Допустим, у меня есть исходная строка. Как перевести ее в этот формат?
Я мог бы и ручками написать, но есть ли что-то готовое?

Пример экранирования:

> `I love cats - they are cool`
>
> `I\ love\ cats\ -\ they\ are\ cool`

Comment: что является спецсимволом зависит от языка, например, синтаксис bash (что является метасимволом в баше) отличается от синтаксиса python (что является специальным символом в строке-константе (string literal)). Какой язык вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @jfs метасимволы bash. Ну, к примеру, при вводе в терминале название папки, содержащее пробел, вы должны перед пробелом поставить "\"

Comment: Не помещайте информацию, необходимую для ответа, в комментарии. Отредактируйте Ваш вопрос вместо этого.

Answer (score 4):

Это стандартное экранирование спец-символов. Есть такой кодек - string-escape.

```
name.encode('string-escape')
```

Comment: LookupError: unknown encoding: string-escape

Comment: попробуйте unicode_escape

Comment: Вы неверно меня поняли. Моя ошибка, сейчас изменю вопрос

Comment: а, ну впринципе вы можете забить свой набор спец символов и обычной заменой вхождения их делать замену...

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы экранировать bash метасимволы в строке, достаточно поместить строку в одинарные кавычки; для этого можно использовать [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> print(shlex.quote("don't tread.."))
'don'"'"'t tread..'
```