# Есть ли в python функция экранирования кавычек?

Tags: python, строки, postgresql

т.е. нужно, чтобы строки типа:

```
string 'test' string
```

конвертировались в

```
string \'test\' string
```

нашёл тут похожую проблему
[Как экранировать все спецсимволы в строке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494797/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5)
но .encode('string-escape') не распознаётся, а shlex.quote делает не то.

Оно, в принципе, просто пишется, но решил спросить прежде, чем велосипеды конструировать, может есть что-то стандартное в языке для этого...

Нужно для корректного экспорта в PostgreSQL. т.е. у меня Where-Statement строится в python, потом в Delphi соединяется с основным запросом и отправляется в BD. Если параметры содержат апострофы, начинаются проблемы. Парсить весь ответ в Delphi тоже не хотелось бы, проще сразу от phyton получать в правильном виде

Comment: В библиотеках для работы с PostgreSQL такие функции должны быть, не?

Comment: Можете подробнее описать для чего вам это? Вы планируете создавать SQL при помощи Python? Можете привести реальные примеры строк, которые не будут работать в PostgreSQL?

Comment: @MaxU типа такого получается: WHERE fieldname LIKE('xxxx'A'-%') потому, что подставляется строка "xxxx'A'-%" как параметр... и, конечно, оно вызывает исключение

Comment: @Isaev, используйте `prepared statements` для литералов - об остальном позаботиться клиент sqlalchemy/psycopg2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** судя по уточнению в комментариях речь в вопросе идет об экранировании кавычек в литералах, являющихся частью SQL строки / текста.

Если использовать `prepared statements`, то SQL клиент / драйвер сделает всю грязную работу за вас и в качестве бонуса вы получите защиту от `SQL injections`.

Пример:

```
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# conn = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@host:port/dbname')
conn = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/dbname')
cur = conn.cursor()

qry = """
SELECT * from table_name WHERE fieldname LIKE(:param_A)
"""
params=("xxxx'A'-%", )

cur.execute(qry, params=params)

for row in cur.fetchall():
    #print(row) 
    #...
```

---

Используйте модуль `json`:

```
import json

s = "string 'test' string"
escaped = json.dumps(s)
```

значение переменной в iPython:

```
In [102]: escaped
Out[102]: '"string \'test\' string"'
```

Проверка через запись в файл:

```
In [103]: from pathlib import Path

In [104]: Path("c:/temp/out.txt").write_text(escaped)
Out[104]: 22

In [105]: Path("c:/temp/out.txt").read_text()
Out[105]: '"string \'test\' string"'
```

c:/temp/out.txt:

```
"string 'test' string"
```

Comment: хмм... а как увидеть что внутри? он их при печати снова убирает? print(escaped) печатает изначальную строку

Comment: @Isaev, лучшим тестом будет запись переменной в текстовый файл и проверить содержимое

Comment: @Isaev, хммм..., а ведь в данном случае бекслеши и не нужны... Может вам просто `s.replace("'", r"\'")` подойдет?

Comment: благодараю. наверное да, просто заменить проще будет